# Golang cannot find module providing package {PACKAGE_NAME}: working directory is not part of a module

Tags: go, dependencies, dep

I am wondering what is going on with my local build? I want to test deployment to DEV to fix problem, but I can’t build.
make build-mac

```
env GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags "-s -w -X main.version=v1.0.20-16-ga0298c0 -X main.commit=a0298c0 -X main.branch=master -X main.buildDate=2020-05-20T11:12:36-0700" -o backend main.go
main.go:7:2: cannot find module providing package github.com/LF-Engineering/vulnerability-detection/backend/cmd: working directory is not part of a module
main.go:8:2: cannot find module providing package github.com/LF-Engineering/vulnerability-detection/backend/v2: working directory is not part of a module
make: *** [build-mac] Error 1
```

Same with building the lambda:

````
dep ensure -v
Building a staticlly linked binary...
env CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags "-s -w -X main.version=v1.0.20-16-ga0298c0 -X main.commit=a0298c0 -X main.branch=master -X main.buildDate=2020-05-20T11:26:15-0700" -tags aws_lambda -o backend_aws_lambda main.go
main.go:7:2: cannot find module providing package github.com/LF-Engineering/vulnerability-detection/backend/cmd: working directory is not part of a module
main.go:8:2: cannot find module providing package github.com/LF-Engineering/vulnerability-detection/backend/v2: working directory is not part of a module
make: *** [build_aws_lambda] Error 1```

I have done a clean build, removed vendor and re-tried.
Wonder if this is a go version problem? Recently updated:
```go version             
go version go1.14.3 darwin/amd64
````

It would be nice to resolve the odd issue related to the package setup and vendor/Gopkg.toml/lock being in the parent folder.
we should use go mod as this is going to be the standard moving forward
just, I had trouble using it with the directory structure for some reason.

Answer (score 24):

I found the same issue before, and I sovled this issue, change environment variables, `GO111MODULE` from `on` to `auto`

Open up File/Preferences/Settings  and search for “go tools env vars”
Click “Edit in settings.json” and set GO111MODULE to `auto`
(instructions from https://dev.to/codeboten/disabling-go-modules-in-visual-studio-code-31mp)

Comment: It works not well. After that I`ve got another exception: ```cmd/main.go:5:2: cannot find package "${GIT}/app/api" in any of:
 /usr/local/go/src/${GIT}/app/api (from $GOROOT)
 /go/src/${GIT}app/api (from $GOPATH)
```