# no required module provides package SDL2

Tags: go, sdl-2

I am trying to import sdl2 package from https://github.com/veandco/go-sdl2. I followed all the steps that appear on readme.md for Windows. Installing mingw64 and do on cmd:

```
go get -v github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/sdl
```

It works okay, but when I tried to do:

```
go run .\sdl2.go
```

I got this error:

```
sdl2.go:4:2: no required module provides package github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/sdl: working directory is not part of a module
```

In my other computer works perfect but when I clone this repository and install the package on the other laptop I had a lot of issues. To get more info about the case I put my test source here to brig more information:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/sdl"
    "fmt"
)

const winWidth, winHeight int = 800, 600



type color struct {
    r, g, b byte
}

func setPixel(x, y int, c color, pixels []byte) {
    index := (y * winWidth + x) * 4

    if index < len(pixels)-4 && index >= 0 {
    pixels[index] = c.r
    pixels[index+1] = c.g
    pixels[index+2] = c.b
    }
}

func main() {
    winWidth := 800
    winHeight := 600

    window,err := sdl.CreateWindow("Testing SDL2", sdl.WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, sdl.WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        int32(winWidth) ,int32(winHeight), sdl.WINDOW_SHOWN)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return 
    }
    defer window.Destroy()

    renderer, err := sdl.CreateRenderer(window, -1, sdl.RENDERER_ACCELERATED)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer renderer.Destroy()

    tex, err  := renderer.CreateTexture(sdl.PIXELFORMAT_ABGR8888, sdl.TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, int32(winWidth), int32(winHeight))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer tex.Destroy()

    pixels := make([]byte, winWidth*winHeight*4)

    for y := 0; y < winHeight; y++ {
        for x := 0; x < winWidth; x++ {
            setPixel(x,y, color{byte(x % 255),byte(y % 255), 0}, pixels)
        }
    }
    tex.Update(nil,pixels,winWidth*4)
    renderer.Copy(tex,nil,nil)
    renderer.Present()

    sdl.Delay(2000)

}
```

Comment: `go run .\sdl2.go` are you sure in this backslash ?

Comment: @bobra yes it works on the other computer, I used the autocomplet from powershell and works

Comment: @Dailo141 you have no package declared in your file, add `package main` to the 1st line of your file

Comment: yes, it is but i type wrong before I post, I've just edited right now

Comment: do you have modules init ? have u called `go mod init my_module_name` ?

Comment: also look this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61921282/golang-cannot-find-module-providing-package-package-name-working-directory-is

Comment: Never use `go run <file>.go`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [New module changes in Go 1.16](https://blog.golang.org/go116-module-changes) blog

> The go command now builds packages in module-aware mode by default, even when no go.mod is present. This is a big step toward using modules in all projects.

as suggested in the blog change the value for GO111MODULE to auto `go env -w GO111MODULE=auto` would fix the issue.

Comment: Note that the [blog](https://blog.golang.org/go116-module-changes) also states "Go 1.17 will ignore GO111MODULE"; so setting `GO111MODULE=auto` is not a long term fix (plan on using modules going forward; the [getting started tutorial](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started) covers the basics).