# How to run a go program when it imports a file from a different folder?

Tags: go, goland

[image]

As we see neither run nor build is doing the needful. Clearly I am missing something.
How can I include lruCache in my main which is in a different folder ?

Comment: In Go 1.16 (which I assume you are using) [module-aware mode is the default](https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#go-command). Your best option is to run `go mod init` as per the [getting started tutorial](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no required module provides package SDL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66267267/no-required-module-provides-package-sdl2)

Answer (score 1):

`github.com/lrucache` is not a valid import path. That is a Github organization, not a repository. You are presumably trying to install a specific package hosted somewhere within that org.

Answer (score -1):

GOPATH=~/Document/goworkspace go run main.go